# Shimano rear hub body compatibility

Tags: shimano, hub, freewheel

My free hub body has cracked and im looking to replace it. I have discovered it uses a 14mm hex key to remove. I cannot find a freehub body for sale that matches m785.

Will a "m760-m765" body fit my "m785" hub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/EV/bikecomponents/FH/EV-FH-M785-3174_v1_m56577569830753751.pdf) Shimano tech doc has the relevant part numbers for you.

Y3CZ98040, I think. You may want just part of it though.

It also has a handy interchangeability table, that tells me a freehub body from an M985 or M775 would work too, but might be the wrong colour.

You can look up more [here](http://techdocs.shimano.com/techdocs/blevel.jsp?ASSORTMENT%3C%3East_id=1408474395181679&FOLDER%3C%3Efolder_id=2534374302051947).

Comment: Great. Thanks. Youve also helped me understand the compatibility table on the tech docs.

Comment: An update. I ended up ordering the whole rear hub again as it was just £4 more than the cheapest compatible freehub body. I intend to use the bearings, seals etc to service this one. and have a spare (bodyless) hub and QR left over.